# What does this error mean when installing namecoin?

Tags: ubuntu, compiling, libraries

I'm trying to set up namecoin, but I get the following error on running makefile.unix:

```
$ g++ -c -O2 -Wno-invalid-offsetof -Wformat -g -D__WXDEBUG__ -DNOPCH DFOURWAYSSE2 -DUSE_SSL -DUSE_UPNP=0 -o obj/nogui/net.o net.cpp

In file included from net.cpp:10:
/usr/include/miniupnpc/upnpcommands.h:11:30: error: portlistingparse.h: No such file or directory
/usr/include/miniupnpc/upnpcommands.h:13:28: error: miniupnpctypes.h: No such file or directory
In file included from net.cpp:10:
/usr/include/miniupnpc/upnpcommands.h:25: error: ‘UNSIGNED_INTEGER’ does not name a type
/usr/include/miniupnpc/upnpcommands.h:29: error: ‘UNSIGNED_INTEGER’ does not name a type
/usr/include/miniupnpc/upnpcommands.h:33: error: ‘UNSIGNED_INTEGER’ does not name a type
/usr/include/miniupnpc/upnpcommands.h:37: error: ‘UNSIGNED_INTEGER’ does not name a type
/usr/include/miniupnpc/miniupnpc.h: In function ‘void ThreadMapPort2(void*)’:
/usr/include/miniupnpc/miniupnpc.h:53: error: too few arguments to function ‘UPNPDev* upnpDiscover(int, const char*, const char*, int, int, int*)’
net.cpp:906: error: at this point in file
/usr/include/miniupnpc/upnpcommands.h:117: error: too few arguments to function ‘int UPNP_AddPortMapping(const char*, const char*, const char*, const char*, const char*, const char*, const char*, const char*, const char*)’
net.cpp:920: error: at this point in file
make: *** [obj/nogui/net.o] Error 1
```

I think the issue may be Berkeley DB but I don't know how to check that. Anybody have any idea?

Comment: The latest release of miniupnpc is broken a little.  You might need to copy the missing header files manually from the source directory to the installation directory (`/usr/include/miniupnpc` in your case.)  Last time I've tried, it still produced some errors at later steps, which I didn't know how to overcome.  Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex is correct in his comment, the latest miniupnpc is broken. However you can use the working version here: `http://miniupnp.tuxfamily.org/files/download.php?file=miniupnpc-1.5.tar.gz` and then namecoind will compile fine.